# Blurred colors using epsfig or graphicx in LaTeX

Tags: image, latex, blurry

My code is simple enough, and importing eps images is something I've done before with other matlab-generated content, but for one reason or another I end up with blurred colors in my heatmap when I use epsfig or graphicx to import it into my document.  In the picture below, the right is what shows up if I compile to DVI and open up the document in Yap, and the left is if I simply view the eps in GSView.

[alt text http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/1694/epsproblem.png](http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/1694/epsproblem.png)

Here is my code.  This example is using graphicx, but the idea is the same with epsfig.

> \begin{figure}
>
> \centering
>
> \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{images/ngram3_model_raw.eps}
>
> \caption{The perplexity when compared
>   against the HUB test set}
>
> \end{figure}

Is there perhaps some option I am forgetting?

Comment: The links to the pictures are broken, but I assume the EPS looks fine in GSview. Have you tried compiling your file to PS or PDF and viewing it there? Perhaps it is just Yap that's having problems.

Comment: I have tried outputting to other formats with no avail.  Could you elaborate on what you mean, "the links to the pictures are broken"?

Comment: You wrote "in the picture below", but all I see is a little red x icon.

Comment: I suggest trying to ask the question again at http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with DVI, but if I compiled to pdf the pictures were fine

Comment: You're right.  My DVI Viewer (Yap) appears to have bugs that no longer appear after conversion to pdf.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is bilinear interpolation. It is done by the viewer. Probably Matlab defines the plot contents as a pixmap (I guess you use imagesc?).

The solution is not straightforward. It may help to use a different processing chain (as WtFudgE pointed out) that will lead the data end up in a format where it is not interpolated anymore. You may also use a different viewer that does not interpolate and I would assume that a printer would also not interpolate. This can again be dependent of the application you print from.

Sorry that I don't have a solution for you; at least you now have some new words to search for in Google. ;)